# Trying to Search Many Files for Many Strings Containing Spaces Simultaneously Using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have files of which I'm trying to parse text using Powershell. They aren't text files, but can be opened with notepad. The string I'm looking for has spaces i.e. "7 0 4 5 8 7 D" but I don't get any results when I use the following command:

```
Get-Content -Path "...\Desktop\MAY 2018\*.wiff" | Where-Object {$_ -like '*7 0 4 5 8 7 D*'}
```

My goal is to search entire folders of these files with many different strings simultaneously, and have the search return which files contain which strings. I'm using Get-Content because these files are not text files per say, but can be parsed (I believe) after the Get-Content command via pipeline to the Where-Object function. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: For a binary file `Get-Content` will not do I think. Better use `$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("path_to_the_file")` to read the file as an array of bytes end plough through that. [File.ReadAllBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readallbytes?view=netframework-4.7.2). p.s. please tag your question `PowerShell`

Answer (score 1):

Check that those are indeed spaces between the not space characters.
You can also try regular expression to do your search. Something like

`Where-Object {$_ -match "7\s0\s4\s5\s8\s7\sD"}` or

`Where-Object {$_ -match "7.0.4.5.8.7.D"}`

Comment: The search seems to carry out with the "7.0.4.5.8.7.D" method, but at the end I don't see the results in the console. Is there a way to print these results somewhere? Either that, or there's no hits, meaning that something else might be wrong.